# How to count the amount of times an element appears seperately within a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, random, counting

Beginner at using Mathematica, and having trouble with nested lists. For example, the following output for 15 coinflips every day for a year:

```
cointoss1 = Table[cointoss2 = RandomChoice[{"H", "T"}, 15], 365]
```

Which gives an output like:

```
{{"H", "T", "H", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "H", "T", "T", "H", "H", 
  "T", "T"}, {"H", "H", "H", "T", "H", "T", "H", "H", "H", "T", "T", 
  "H", "T", "H", "T"}...
```

My question is how would I be able to count the number of times I get a certain element in the list. For example, If I wanted to count how many heads I get within each list how would I go about doing it. I've tried using count -

```
Count[cointoss1, "H"]
```

Every time I tried it I have gotten an output of 0. I want to get it in a list like output for the number of heads in each list:
{5,8,...}
Another thing I want to find is the number of lists with x or more heads. So how would I go about doing this? Apologies for the bad formatting, this is my first question.

Comment: try `Count[#, "H"] & /@ cointoss1`?

Comment: @kglr, this worked thanks very much

Comment: `Count["H"]  /@  cointoss1`

Comment: Another way would be to use `0` and `1` instead of `"H"` and `"T"`: `cointoss1 = RandomChoice[{0, 1}, {365, 15}];`  Then `Total[cointoss1, {2}]` is the count of `"T"`for each row.